# How to match date in logstash with different white space

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

i have one issue where the data space is having different type of white space in logs. Am using logstash to configure and match the date.
Example as below 
         For this kind of date data : `Jan 25 19:15:20.202`

```
 date {
    match => ["date_batch", "MMM d HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    target => date_batch

}
```

It's works with above example but if the date like below the pattern will fail because of extra space in between day and time

```
Jan 25   19:15:20.202
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You could use more than one pattern in your date filter: `match => ["date_batch", "MMM_d HH:mm:ss.SSS", "MMM__d HH:mm:ss.SSS", "MMM___d HH:mm:ss.SSS"]`.

Comment: yes its works thanks man!! really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine to add multiple timestamp pattern. Please refer the comments